# Unable to Change CSS Property Value on Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now my code is contains an HTML table and a popup which appears when the page is loaded. The HTML table's header bar is fixed, but it only becomes fixed when the ✕ button on the popup is clicked. The popup can be revisited if you were to press the keys `g` or `G`. However the HTML table's header bar will stay fixed and obscure the popup to some extent.

This is what I'm trying to fix. When the `g` or `G` keys are pressed I want the HTML table's header bar to go back to it's original state before the ✕ button was even clicked in the first place.

One way to do this is to change the value of the property `scrollingTop` from `-10` to `-1000` like so:

Activated when the ✕ button is clicked:

```
$(".copyTable").floatThead({
    scrollingTop: -10
});
```

What I want to happen when the keys `g` or `G` have been pressed:

```
$(".copyTable").floatThead({
    scrollingTop: -1000
});
```

Now this is just one way to achieve my goal, you are welcome to use other/easier ways to do the same thing.

Obviously, it wasn't as simple as adding the bit of code that has the `scrollingTop` property set to `-1000` in my keypress function because then I wouldn't be here. I've also tried several other ways to achieve this such as by using a global variable to no avail.

Hopefully you guys can help me out with my problem as I simply can't figure out how to complete what appears to be a simple task. Here's the link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/omxavvtx/2/) but I must warn you the positioning is a little off in the fiddle due to the smaller screen size. It works fine in the snippet but I recommend viewing it in full screen mode for better results.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 71 || e.charCode === 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
        }
    });

  $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);

  $(".close").click(function() {

    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
! function (a) {
    function b(a, b, c) {
        if (8 == g) {
            var d = j.width(),
                e = f.debounce(function () {
                    var a = j.width();
                    d != a && (d = a, c())
                }, a);
            j.on(b, e)
        } else j.on(b, f.debounce(c, a))
    }

    function c(a) {
        window.console && window.console && window.console.log && window.console.log(a)
    }

    function d() {
        var b = a('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow-y:scroll;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;width:100%"></div>');
        a("body").append(b);
        var c = b.innerWidth(),
            d = a("div", b).innerWidth();
        return b.remove(), c - d
    }

    function e(a) {
        if (a.dataTableSettings) for (var b = 0; b < a.dataTableSettings.length; b++) {
            var c = a.dataTableSettings[b].nTable;
            if (a[0] == c) return !0
        }
        return !1
    }
    a.floatThead = a.floatThead || {}, a.floatThead.defaults = {
        cellTag: null,
        headerCellSelector: "tr:first>th:visible",
        zIndex: 1001,
        debounceResizeMs: 10,
        useAbsolutePositioning: !0,
        scrollingTop: 0,
        scrollingBottom: 0,
        scrollContainer: function () {
            return a([])
        },
        getSizingRow: function (a) {
            return a.find("tbody tr:visible:first>*")
        },
        floatTableClass: "floatThead-table",
        floatWrapperClass: "floatThead-wrapper",
        floatContainerClass: "floatThead-container",
        copyTableClass: !0,
        debug: !1
    };
    var f = window._,
        g = function () {
            for (var a = 3, b = document.createElement("b"), c = b.all || []; a = 1 + a, b.innerHTML = "<\!--[if gt IE " + a + "]><i><![endif]-->", c[0];);
            return a > 4 ? a : document.documentMode
        }(),
        h = null,
        i = function () {
            if (g) return !1;
            var b = a("<table><colgroup><col></colgroup><tbody><tr><td style='width:10px'></td></tbody></table>");
            a("body").append(b);
            var c = b.find("col").width();
            return b.remove(), 0 == c
        }, j = a(window),
        k = 0;
    a.fn.floatThead = function (l) {
        if (l = l || {}, !f && (f = window._ || a.floatThead._, !f)) throw new Error("jquery.floatThead-slim.js requires underscore. You should use the non-lite version since you do not have underscore.");
        if (8 > g) return this;
        if (null == h && (h = i(), h && (document.createElement("fthtr"), document.createElement("fthtd"), document.createElement("fthfoot"))), f.isString(l)) {
            var m = l,
                n = this;
            return this.filter("table").each(function () {
                var b = a(this).data("floatThead-attached");
                if (b && f.isFunction(b[m])) {
                    var c = b[m]();
                    "undefined" != typeof c && (n = c)
                }
            }), n
        }
        var o = a.extend({}, a.floatThead.defaults || {}, l);
        return a.each(l, function (b) {
            b in a.floatThead.defaults || !o.debug || c("jQuery.floatThead: used [" + b + "] key to init plugin, but that param is not an option for the plugin. Valid options are: " + f.keys(a.floatThead.defaults).join(", "))
        }), this.filter(":not(." + o.floatTableClass + ")").each(function () {
            function c(a) {
                return a + ".fth-" + y + ".floatTHead"
            }

            function i() {
                var b = 0;
                A.find("tr:visible").each(function () {
                    b += a(this).outerHeight(!0)
                }), Z.outerHeight(b), $.outerHeight(b)
            }

            function l() {
                var a = z.outerWidth(),
                    b = I.width() || a;
                if (X.width(b - F.vertical), O) {
                    var c = 100 * a / (b - F.vertical);
                    S.css("width", c + "%")
                } else S.outerWidth(a)
            }

            function m() {
                C = (f.isFunction(o.scrollingTop) ? o.scrollingTop(z) : o.scrollingTop) || 0, D = (f.isFunction(o.scrollingBottom) ? o.scrollingBottom(z) : o.scrollingBottom) || 0
            }

            function n() {
                var b, c;
                if (V) b = U.find("col").length;
                else {
                    var d;
                    d = null == o.cellTag && o.headerCellSelector ? o.headerCellSelector : "tr:first>" + o.cellTag, c = A.find(d), b = 0, c.each(function () {
                        b += parseInt(a(this).attr("colspan") || 1, 10)
                    })
                }
                if (b != H) {
                    H = b;
                    for (var e = [], f = [], g = [], i = 0; b > i; i++) e.push('<th class="floatThead-col"/>'), f.push("<col/>"), g.push("<fthtd style='display:table-cell;height:0;width:auto;'/>");
                    f = f.join(""), e = e.join(""), h && (g = g.join(""), W.html(g), bb = W.find("fthtd")), Z.html(e), $ = Z.find("th"), V || U.html(f), _ = U.find("col"), T.html(f), ab = T.find("col")
                }
                return b
            }

            function p() {
                if (!E) {
                    if (E = !0, J) {
                        var a = z.width(),
                            b = Q.width();
                        a > b && z.css("minWidth", a)
                    }
                    z.css(db), S.css(db), S.append(A), B.before(Y), i()
                }
            }

            function q() {
                E && (E = !1, J && z.width(fb), Y.detach(), z.prepend(A), z.css(eb), S.css(eb))
            }

            function r(a) {
                J != a && (J = a, X.css({
                    position: J ? "absolute" : "fixed"
                }))
            }

            function s(a, b, c, d) {
                return h ? c : d ? o.getSizingRow(a, b, c) : b
            }

            function t() {
                var a, b = n();
                return function () {
                    var c = s(z, _, bb, g);
                    if (c.length == b && b > 0) {
                        if (!V) for (a = 0; b > a; a++) _.eq(a).css("width", "");
                        q();
                        var d = [];
                        for (a = 0; b > a; a++) d[a] = c.get(a).offsetWidth;
                        for (a = 0; b > a; a++) ab.eq(a).width(d[a]), _.eq(a).width(d[a]);
                        p()
                    } else S.append(A), z.css(eb), S.css(eb), i()
                }
            }

            function u(a) {
                var b = I.css("border-" + a + "-width"),
                    c = 0;
                return b && ~b.indexOf("px") && (c = parseInt(b, 10)), c
            }

            function v() {
                var a, b = I.scrollTop(),
                    c = 0,
                    d = L ? K.outerHeight(!0) : 0,
                    e = M ? d : -d,
                    f = X.height(),
                    g = z.offset(),
                    i = 0;
                if (O) {
                    var k = I.offset();
                    c = g.top - k.top + b, L && M && (c += d), c -= u("top"), i = u("left")
                } else a = g.top - C - f + D + F.horizontal;
                var l = j.scrollTop(),
                    m = j.scrollLeft(),
                    n = I.scrollLeft();
                return b = I.scrollTop(),

                function (k) {
                    if ("windowScroll" == k ? (l = j.scrollTop(), m = j.scrollLeft()) : "containerScroll" == k ? (b = I.scrollTop(), n = I.scrollLeft()) : "init" != k && (l = j.scrollTop(), m = j.scrollLeft(), b = I.scrollTop(), n = I.scrollLeft()), !h || !(0 > l || 0 > m)) {
                        if (R) r("windowScrollDone" == k ? !0 : !1);
                        else if ("windowScrollDone" == k) return null;
                        g = z.offset(), L && M && (g.top += d);
                        var o, s, t = z.outerHeight();
                        if (O && J) {
                            if (c >= b) {
                                var u = c - b;
                                o = u > 0 ? u : 0
                            } else o = P ? 0 : b;
                            s = i
                        } else !O && J ? (l > a + t + e ? o = t - f + e : g.top > l + C ? (o = 0, q()) : (o = C + l - g.top + c + (M ? d : 0), p()), s = 0) : O && !J ? (c > b || b - c > t ? (o = g.top - l, q()) : (o = g.top + b - l - c, p()), s = g.left + n - m) : O || J || (l > a + t + e ? o = t + C - l + a + e : g.top > l + C ? (o = g.top - l, p()) : o = C, s = g.left - m);
                        return {
                            top: o,
                            left: s
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function w() {
                var a = null,
                    b = null,
                    c = null;
                return function (d, e, f) {
                    null == d || a == d.top && b == d.left || (X.css({
                        top: d.top,
                        left: d.left
                    }), a = d.top, b = d.left), e && l(), f && i();
                    var g = I.scrollLeft();
                    J && c == g || (X.scrollLeft(g), c = g)
                }
            }

            function x() {
                if (I.length) {
                    var a = I.width(),
                        b = I.height(),
                        c = z.height(),
                        d = z.width(),
                        e = d > a ? G : 0,
                        f = c > b ? G : 0;
                    F.horizontal = d > a - f ? G : 0, F.vertical = c > b - e ? G : 0
                }
            }
            var y = k,
                z = a(this);
            if (z.data("floatThead-attached")) return !0;
            if (!z.is("table")) throw new Error('jQuery.floatThead must be run on a table element. ex: $("table").floatThead();');
            var A = z.find("thead:first"),
                B = z.find("tbody:first");
            if (0 == A.length) throw new Error("jQuery.floatThead must be run on a table that contains a <thead> element");
            var C, D, E = !1,
                F = {
                    vertical: 0,
                    horizontal: 0
                }, G = d(),
                H = 0,
                I = o.scrollContainer(z) || a([]),
                J = o.useAbsolutePositioning;
            null == J && (J = o.scrollContainer(z).length);
            var K = z.find("caption"),
                L = 1 == K.length;
            if (L) var M = "top" === (K.css("caption-side") || K.attr("align") || "top");
            var N = a('<fthfoot style="display:table-footer-group;"/>'),
                O = I.length > 0,
                P = !1,
                Q = a([]),
                R = 9 >= g && !O && J,
                S = a("<table/>"),
                T = a("<colgroup/>"),
                U = z.find("colgroup:first"),
                V = !0;
            0 == U.length && (U = a("<colgroup/>"), V = !1);
            var W = a('<fthrow style="display:table-row;height:0;"/>'),
                X = a('<div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>'),
                Y = a("<thead/>"),
                Z = a('<tr class="size-row"/>'),
                $ = a([]),
                _ = a([]),
                ab = a([]),
                bb = a([]);
            if (Y.append(Z), z.prepend(U), h && (N.append(W), z.append(N)), S.append(T), X.append(S), o.copyTableClass && S.attr("class", z.attr("class")), S.attr({
                cellpadding: z.attr("cellpadding"),
                cellspacing: z.attr("cellspacing"),
                border: z.attr("border")
            }), S.css({
                borderCollapse: z.css("borderCollapse"),
                border: z.css("border")
            }), S.addClass(o.floatTableClass).css("margin", 0), J) {
                var cb = function (a, b) {
                    var c = a.css("position"),
                        d = "relative" == c || "absolute" == c;
                    if (!d || b) {
                        var e = {
                            paddingLeft: a.css("paddingLeft"),
                            paddingRight: a.css("paddingRight")
                        };
                        X.css(e), a = a.wrap("<div class='" + o.floatWrapperClass + "' style='position: relative; clear:both; padding-top: 0px;'></div>").parent(), P = !0
                    }
                    return a
                };
                O ? (Q = cb(I, !0), Q.append(X)) : (Q = cb(z), z.after(X))
            } else z.after(X);
            X.css({
                position: J ? "absolute" : "fixed",
                marginTop: 0,
                top: J ? 0 : "auto",
                zIndex: o.zIndex
            }), X.addClass(o.floatContainerClass), m();
            var db = {
                "table-layout": "fixed"
            }, eb = {
                "table-layout": z.css("tableLayout") || "auto"
            }, fb = z[0].style.width || "";
            x();
            var gb, hb = function () {
                (gb = t())()
            };
            hb();
            var ib = v(),
                jb = w();
            jb(ib("init"), !0);
            var kb = f.debounce(function () {
                jb(ib("windowScrollDone"), !1)
            }, 300),
                lb = function () {
                    jb(ib("windowScroll"), !1), kb()
                }, mb = function () {
                    jb(ib("containerScroll"), !1)
                }, nb = function () {
                    m(), x(), hb(), ib = v(), (jb = w())(ib("resize"), !0, !0)
                }, ob = f.debounce(function () {
                    x(), m(), hb(), ib = v(), jb(ib("reflow"), !0)
                }, 1);
            O ? J ? I.on(c("scroll"), mb) : (I.on(c("scroll"), mb), j.on(c("scroll"), lb)) : j.on(c("scroll"), lb), j.on(c("load"), ob), b(o.debounceResizeMs, c("resize"), nb), z.on("reflow", ob), e(z) && z.on("filter", ob).on("sort", ob).on("page", ob), z.data("floatThead-attached", {
                destroy: function () {
                    var a = ".fth-" + y;
                    q(), z.css(eb), U.remove(), h && N.remove(), Y.parent().length && Y.replaceWith(A), z.off("reflow"), I.off(a), P && (I.length ? I.unwrap() : z.unwrap()), J && z.css("minWidth", ""), X.remove(), z.data("floatThead-attached", !1), j.off(a)
                },
                reflow: function () {
                    ob()
                },
                setHeaderHeight: function () {
                    i()
                },
                getFloatContainer: function () {
                    return X
                },
                getRowGroups: function () {
                    return E ? X.find("thead").add(z.find("tbody,tfoot")) : z.find("thead,tbody,tfoot")
                }
            }), k++
        }), this
    }
}(jQuery),

function (a) {
    a.floatThead = a.floatThead || {}, a.floatThead._ = window._ || function () {
        var b = {}, c = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
            d = ["Arguments", "Function", "String", "Number", "Date", "RegExp"];
        return b.has = function (a, b) {
            return c.call(a, b)
        }, b.keys = function (a) {
            if (a !== Object(a)) throw new TypeError("Invalid object");
            var c = [];
            for (var d in a) b.has(a, d) && c.push(d);
            return c
        }, a.each(d, function () {
            var a = this;
            b["is" + a] = function (b) {
                return Object.prototype.toString.call(b) == "[object " + a + "]"
            }
        }), b.debounce = function (a, b, c) {
            var d, e, f, g, h;
            return function () {
                f = this, e = arguments, g = new Date;
                var i = function () {
                    var j = new Date - g;
                    b > j ? d = setTimeout(i, b - j) : (d = null, c || (h = a.apply(f, e)))
                }, j = c && !d;
                return d || (d = setTimeout(i, b)), j && (h = a.apply(f, e)), h
            }
        }, b
    }()
}(jQuery);

    $(".copyTable").floatThead({
        scrollingTop: -10
    });

  });

});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

table.floatThead-table {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  height: 75px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hidden_table{
/*display:none*/
}

button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2D2D2D;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.close-message {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 9px;
}

.t {
 -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
 -moz-transform-origin: top left;
 -o-transform-origin: top left;
 -ms-transform-origin: top left;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
 -o-transform: scale(0.25);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: pre;
 overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1{left:434.235px;top:35px;letter-spacing:0.1px;}

.s1_1{
 FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
 FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
 FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

          .button {
            font-size: 1em;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #fff;
            border: 2px solid orange;
            border-radius: 20px/50px;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
          }
          .button:hover {
            background: orange;
          }
          .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            height: 157%;
            width: 115%;
            z-index: 2;
          }
          .overlay:target {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            display:none;
          }
          .PopUp {
            margin: 50px auto;
            padding: 0px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 60%;
            position: relative;
            transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
            z-index: 3;
          }
          .PopUp .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            right: 30px;
            transition: all 200ms;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
     z-index: 1;
          }
          .PopUp .close:hover {
            color: orange;
          }
          .PopUp .content {
            max-height: 115%;
            overflow: auto;
          }

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
          .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            height: 157%;
            width: 115%;
          }
}

div:not(#container)  {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
     <div class="PopUp" >
      <a class="close" id="close" href="#">&#x2715;</a>
      <div class="content" id="content">
<div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">

<!-- Begin page background -->
<div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<!-- End page background -->


<!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
<div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Popup</div>

<!-- End text definitions -->

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">
(function(divCount, pageNum) {
for (var i = 1; i < divCount; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById('t' + i.toString(36) + '_' + pageNum);
    if (div !== null) {
        div.style.top = (div.offsetTop * 4) + 'px';
        div.style.left = (div.offsetLeft * 4) + 'px';
        div.style.zoom = '25%';
    }
}
})(49, 1);
</script><![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
     </div>
    </div>
<div class="container" id="container">
<table class="copyTable" id="copyTable">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
      <th>Column 11</th>
      <th>Column 12</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="3">
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="4">
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="item" data-id="5">
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="6">
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="item" data-id="7">
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="8">
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
```

Comment: The snippet appears to work fine when at full screen mode. I think that is a CSS sizing/positionning issue when screen isn't big enought.

Comment: The best way to handle these sort of things, IMHO, is _not_ to fiddle directly with the properties such as `scrollingTop` etc., but to instead define (to yourself) the various _states_ you can be in - original state might be "default", after clicking the ✕ button might be "pinned" and so on. Use a _class_ to represent the states, and add & remove _classes_ as events occur. That way you never end up where you'd have to exactly duplicate a series of actions to get the exact combination of attributes+values. You can limit to one class at a time, or allow for multiples like `class="active pinned"`

Comment: @StephenP As I have previously stated. If you want to use a different/easier method to achieve this go right ahead. It's your answer after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this bit of code to your CSS:

```
.floatThead-container{
  z-index:1 !important;
}
```

It uses `z-index` to make your header bar stay behind the `#PopUp` & `.overlay`.

You could also try this:

```
$('.floatThead-container').css('top','0px');
```

A bit more complicated, as you will have to call it when you press `g` or `G` but you would have to keep calling it every time a scroll is done while the popup is open and stop calling it when it's closed.

I have attached the snippet and here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omxavvtx/6/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 71 || e.charCode === 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
        }
    });

  $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);

  $(".close").click(function() {

    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
! function (a) {
    function b(a, b, c) {
        if (8 == g) {
            var d = j.width(),
                e = f.debounce(function () {
                    var a = j.width();
                    d != a && (d = a, c())
                }, a);
            j.on(b, e)
        } else j.on(b, f.debounce(c, a))
    }

    function c(a) {
        window.console && window.console && window.console.log && window.console.log(a)
    }

    function d() {
        var b = a('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow-y:scroll;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;width:100%"></div>');
        a("body").append(b);
        var c = b.innerWidth(),
            d = a("div", b).innerWidth();
        return b.remove(), c - d
    }

    function e(a) {
        if (a.dataTableSettings) for (var b = 0; b < a.dataTableSettings.length; b++) {
            var c = a.dataTableSettings[b].nTable;
            if (a[0] == c) return !0
        }
        return !1
    }
    a.floatThead = a.floatThead || {}, a.floatThead.defaults = {
        cellTag: null,
        headerCellSelector: "tr:first>th:visible",
        zIndex: 1001,
        debounceResizeMs: 10,
        useAbsolutePositioning: !0,
        scrollingTop: 0,
        scrollingBottom: 0,
        scrollContainer: function () {
            return a([])
        },
        getSizingRow: function (a) {
            return a.find("tbody tr:visible:first>*")
        },
        floatTableClass: "floatThead-table",
        floatWrapperClass: "floatThead-wrapper",
        floatContainerClass: "floatThead-container",
        copyTableClass: !0,
        debug: !1
    };
    var f = window._,
        g = function () {
            for (var a = 3, b = document.createElement("b"), c = b.all || []; a = 1 + a, b.innerHTML = "<\!--[if gt IE " + a + "]><i><![endif]-->", c[0];);
            return a > 4 ? a : document.documentMode
        }(),
        h = null,
        i = function () {
            if (g) return !1;
            var b = a("<table><colgroup><col></colgroup><tbody><tr><td style='width:10px'></td></tbody></table>");
            a("body").append(b);
            var c = b.find("col").width();
            return b.remove(), 0 == c
        }, j = a(window),
        k = 0;
    a.fn.floatThead = function (l) {
        if (l = l || {}, !f && (f = window._ || a.floatThead._, !f)) throw new Error("jquery.floatThead-slim.js requires underscore. You should use the non-lite version since you do not have underscore.");
        if (8 > g) return this;
        if (null == h && (h = i(), h && (document.createElement("fthtr"), document.createElement("fthtd"), document.createElement("fthfoot"))), f.isString(l)) {
            var m = l,
                n = this;
            return this.filter("table").each(function () {
                var b = a(this).data("floatThead-attached");
                if (b && f.isFunction(b[m])) {
                    var c = b[m]();
                    "undefined" != typeof c && (n = c)
                }
            }), n
        }
        var o = a.extend({}, a.floatThead.defaults || {}, l);
        return a.each(l, function (b) {
            b in a.floatThead.defaults || !o.debug || c("jQuery.floatThead: used [" + b + "] key to init plugin, but that param is not an option for the plugin. Valid options are: " + f.keys(a.floatThead.defaults).join(", "))
        }), this.filter(":not(." + o.floatTableClass + ")").each(function () {
            function c(a) {
                return a + ".fth-" + y + ".floatTHead"
            }

            function i() {
                var b = 0;
                A.find("tr:visible").each(function () {
                    b += a(this).outerHeight(!0)
                }), Z.outerHeight(b), $.outerHeight(b)
            }

            function l() {
                var a = z.outerWidth(),
                    b = I.width() || a;
                if (X.width(b - F.vertical), O) {
                    var c = 100 * a / (b - F.vertical);
                    S.css("width", c + "%")
                } else S.outerWidth(a)
            }

            function m() {
                C = (f.isFunction(o.scrollingTop) ? o.scrollingTop(z) : o.scrollingTop) || 0, D = (f.isFunction(o.scrollingBottom) ? o.scrollingBottom(z) : o.scrollingBottom) || 0
            }

            function n() {
                var b, c;
                if (V) b = U.find("col").length;
                else {
                    var d;
                    d = null == o.cellTag && o.headerCellSelector ? o.headerCellSelector : "tr:first>" + o.cellTag, c = A.find(d), b = 0, c.each(function () {
                        b += parseInt(a(this).attr("colspan") || 1, 10)
                    })
                }
                if (b != H) {
                    H = b;
                    for (var e = [], f = [], g = [], i = 0; b > i; i++) e.push('<th class="floatThead-col"/>'), f.push("<col/>"), g.push("<fthtd style='display:table-cell;height:0;width:auto;'/>");
                    f = f.join(""), e = e.join(""), h && (g = g.join(""), W.html(g), bb = W.find("fthtd")), Z.html(e), $ = Z.find("th"), V || U.html(f), _ = U.find("col"), T.html(f), ab = T.find("col")
                }
                return b
            }

            function p() {
                if (!E) {
                    if (E = !0, J) {
                        var a = z.width(),
                            b = Q.width();
                        a > b && z.css("minWidth", a)
                    }
                    z.css(db), S.css(db), S.append(A), B.before(Y), i()
                }
            }

            function q() {
                E && (E = !1, J && z.width(fb), Y.detach(), z.prepend(A), z.css(eb), S.css(eb))
            }

            function r(a) {
                J != a && (J = a, X.css({
                    position: J ? "absolute" : "fixed"
                }))
            }

            function s(a, b, c, d) {
                return h ? c : d ? o.getSizingRow(a, b, c) : b
            }

            function t() {
                var a, b = n();
                return function () {
                    var c = s(z, _, bb, g);
                    if (c.length == b && b > 0) {
                        if (!V) for (a = 0; b > a; a++) _.eq(a).css("width", "");
                        q();
                        var d = [];
                        for (a = 0; b > a; a++) d[a] = c.get(a).offsetWidth;
                        for (a = 0; b > a; a++) ab.eq(a).width(d[a]), _.eq(a).width(d[a]);
                        p()
                    } else S.append(A), z.css(eb), S.css(eb), i()
                }
            }

            function u(a) {
                var b = I.css("border-" + a + "-width"),
                    c = 0;
                return b && ~b.indexOf("px") && (c = parseInt(b, 10)), c
            }

            function v() {
                var a, b = I.scrollTop(),
                    c = 0,
                    d = L ? K.outerHeight(!0) : 0,
                    e = M ? d : -d,
                    f = X.height(),
                    g = z.offset(),
                    i = 0;
                if (O) {
                    var k = I.offset();
                    c = g.top - k.top + b, L && M && (c += d), c -= u("top"), i = u("left")
                } else a = g.top - C - f + D + F.horizontal;
                var l = j.scrollTop(),
                    m = j.scrollLeft(),
                    n = I.scrollLeft();
                return b = I.scrollTop(),

                function (k) {
                    if ("windowScroll" == k ? (l = j.scrollTop(), m = j.scrollLeft()) : "containerScroll" == k ? (b = I.scrollTop(), n = I.scrollLeft()) : "init" != k && (l = j.scrollTop(), m = j.scrollLeft(), b = I.scrollTop(), n = I.scrollLeft()), !h || !(0 > l || 0 > m)) {
                        if (R) r("windowScrollDone" == k ? !0 : !1);
                        else if ("windowScrollDone" == k) return null;
                        g = z.offset(), L && M && (g.top += d);
                        var o, s, t = z.outerHeight();
                        if (O && J) {
                            if (c >= b) {
                                var u = c - b;
                                o = u > 0 ? u : 0
                            } else o = P ? 0 : b;
                            s = i
                        } else !O && J ? (l > a + t + e ? o = t - f + e : g.top > l + C ? (o = 0, q()) : (o = C + l - g.top + c + (M ? d : 0), p()), s = 0) : O && !J ? (c > b || b - c > t ? (o = g.top - l, q()) : (o = g.top + b - l - c, p()), s = g.left + n - m) : O || J || (l > a + t + e ? o = t + C - l + a + e : g.top > l + C ? (o = g.top - l, p()) : o = C, s = g.left - m);
                        return {
                            top: o,
                            left: s
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function w() {
                var a = null,
                    b = null,
                    c = null;
                return function (d, e, f) {
                    null == d || a == d.top && b == d.left || (X.css({
                        top: d.top,
                        left: d.left
                    }), a = d.top, b = d.left), e && l(), f && i();
                    var g = I.scrollLeft();
                    J && c == g || (X.scrollLeft(g), c = g)
                }
            }

            function x() {
                if (I.length) {
                    var a = I.width(),
                        b = I.height(),
                        c = z.height(),
                        d = z.width(),
                        e = d > a ? G : 0,
                        f = c > b ? G : 0;
                    F.horizontal = d > a - f ? G : 0, F.vertical = c > b - e ? G : 0
                }
            }
            var y = k,
                z = a(this);
            if (z.data("floatThead-attached")) return !0;
            if (!z.is("table")) throw new Error('jQuery.floatThead must be run on a table element. ex: $("table").floatThead();');
            var A = z.find("thead:first"),
                B = z.find("tbody:first");
            if (0 == A.length) throw new Error("jQuery.floatThead must be run on a table that contains a <thead> element");
            var C, D, E = !1,
                F = {
                    vertical: 0,
                    horizontal: 0
                }, G = d(),
                H = 0,
                I = o.scrollContainer(z) || a([]),
                J = o.useAbsolutePositioning;
            null == J && (J = o.scrollContainer(z).length);
            var K = z.find("caption"),
                L = 1 == K.length;
            if (L) var M = "top" === (K.css("caption-side") || K.attr("align") || "top");
            var N = a('<fthfoot style="display:table-footer-group;"/>'),
                O = I.length > 0,
                P = !1,
                Q = a([]),
                R = 9 >= g && !O && J,
                S = a("<table/>"),
                T = a("<colgroup/>"),
                U = z.find("colgroup:first"),
                V = !0;
            0 == U.length && (U = a("<colgroup/>"), V = !1);
            var W = a('<fthrow style="display:table-row;height:0;"/>'),
                X = a('<div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>'),
                Y = a("<thead/>"),
                Z = a('<tr class="size-row"/>'),
                $ = a([]),
                _ = a([]),
                ab = a([]),
                bb = a([]);
            if (Y.append(Z), z.prepend(U), h && (N.append(W), z.append(N)), S.append(T), X.append(S), o.copyTableClass && S.attr("class", z.attr("class")), S.attr({
                cellpadding: z.attr("cellpadding"),
                cellspacing: z.attr("cellspacing"),
                border: z.attr("border")
            }), S.css({
                borderCollapse: z.css("borderCollapse"),
                border: z.css("border")
            }), S.addClass(o.floatTableClass).css("margin", 0), J) {
                var cb = function (a, b) {
                    var c = a.css("position"),
                        d = "relative" == c || "absolute" == c;
                    if (!d || b) {
                        var e = {
                            paddingLeft: a.css("paddingLeft"),
                            paddingRight: a.css("paddingRight")
                        };
                        X.css(e), a = a.wrap("<div class='" + o.floatWrapperClass + "' style='position: relative; clear:both; padding-top: 0px;'></div>").parent(), P = !0
                    }
                    return a
                };
                O ? (Q = cb(I, !0), Q.append(X)) : (Q = cb(z), z.after(X))
            } else z.after(X);
            X.css({
                position: J ? "absolute" : "fixed",
                marginTop: 0,
                top: J ? 0 : "auto",
                zIndex: o.zIndex
            }), X.addClass(o.floatContainerClass), m();
            var db = {
                "table-layout": "fixed"
            }, eb = {
                "table-layout": z.css("tableLayout") || "auto"
            }, fb = z[0].style.width || "";
            x();
            var gb, hb = function () {
                (gb = t())()
            };
            hb();
            var ib = v(),
                jb = w();
            jb(ib("init"), !0);
            var kb = f.debounce(function () {
                jb(ib("windowScrollDone"), !1)
            }, 300),
                lb = function () {
                    jb(ib("windowScroll"), !1), kb()
                }, mb = function () {
                    jb(ib("containerScroll"), !1)
                }, nb = function () {
                    m(), x(), hb(), ib = v(), (jb = w())(ib("resize"), !0, !0)
                }, ob = f.debounce(function () {
                    x(), m(), hb(), ib = v(), jb(ib("reflow"), !0)
                }, 1);
            O ? J ? I.on(c("scroll"), mb) : (I.on(c("scroll"), mb), j.on(c("scroll"), lb)) : j.on(c("scroll"), lb), j.on(c("load"), ob), b(o.debounceResizeMs, c("resize"), nb), z.on("reflow", ob), e(z) && z.on("filter", ob).on("sort", ob).on("page", ob), z.data("floatThead-attached", {
                destroy: function () {
                    var a = ".fth-" + y;
                    q(), z.css(eb), U.remove(), h && N.remove(), Y.parent().length && Y.replaceWith(A), z.off("reflow"), I.off(a), P && (I.length ? I.unwrap() : z.unwrap()), J && z.css("minWidth", ""), X.remove(), z.data("floatThead-attached", !1), j.off(a)
                },
                reflow: function () {
                    ob()
                },
                setHeaderHeight: function () {
                    i()
                },
                getFloatContainer: function () {
                    return X
                },
                getRowGroups: function () {
                    return E ? X.find("thead").add(z.find("tbody,tfoot")) : z.find("thead,tbody,tfoot")
                }
            }), k++
        }), this
    }
}(jQuery),

function (a) {
    a.floatThead = a.floatThead || {}, a.floatThead._ = window._ || function () {
        var b = {}, c = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
            d = ["Arguments", "Function", "String", "Number", "Date", "RegExp"];
        return b.has = function (a, b) {
            return c.call(a, b)
        }, b.keys = function (a) {
            if (a !== Object(a)) throw new TypeError("Invalid object");
            var c = [];
            for (var d in a) b.has(a, d) && c.push(d);
            return c
        }, a.each(d, function () {
            var a = this;
            b["is" + a] = function (b) {
                return Object.prototype.toString.call(b) == "[object " + a + "]"
            }
        }), b.debounce = function (a, b, c) {
            var d, e, f, g, h;
            return function () {
                f = this, e = arguments, g = new Date;
                var i = function () {
                    var j = new Date - g;
                    b > j ? d = setTimeout(i, b - j) : (d = null, c || (h = a.apply(f, e)))
                }, j = c && !d;
                return d || (d = setTimeout(i, b)), j && (h = a.apply(f, e)), h
            }
        }, b
    }()
}(jQuery);

    $(".copyTable").floatThead({
        scrollingTop: -10
    });

  });

});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

table.floatThead-table {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  height: 75px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hidden_table{
/*display:none*/
}

button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2D2D2D;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.close-message {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 9px;
}

.t {
 -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
 -moz-transform-origin: top left;
 -o-transform-origin: top left;
 -ms-transform-origin: top left;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
 -o-transform: scale(0.25);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: pre;
 overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1{left:434.235px;top:35px;letter-spacing:0.1px;}

.s1_1{
 FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
 FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
 color: rgb(0,0,0);
 FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

          .button {
            font-size: 1em;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #fff;
            border: 2px solid orange;
            border-radius: 20px/50px;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
          }
          .button:hover {
            background: orange;
          }
          .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            height: 157%;
            width: 115%;
            z-index: 2;
          }
          .overlay:target {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            display:none;
          }
          .PopUp {
            margin: 50px auto;
            padding: 0px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 60%;
            position: relative;
            transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
            z-index: 3;
          }
          .PopUp .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            right: 30px;
            transition: all 200ms;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
     z-index: 1;
          }
          .PopUp .close:hover {
            color: orange;
          }
          .PopUp .content {
            max-height: 115%;
            overflow: auto;
          }

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
          .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            height: 157%;
            width: 115%;
          }
}

div:not(#container)  {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.floatThead-container{
  z-index:1 !important;
}
```

```html
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
     <div class="PopUp" >
      <a class="close" id="close" href="#">&#x2715;</a>
      <div class="content" id="content">
<div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">

<!-- Begin page background -->
<div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<!-- End page background -->


<!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
<div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Popup</div>

<!-- End text definitions -->

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">
(function(divCount, pageNum) {
for (var i = 1; i < divCount; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById('t' + i.toString(36) + '_' + pageNum);
    if (div !== null) {
        div.style.top = (div.offsetTop * 4) + 'px';
        div.style.left = (div.offsetLeft * 4) + 'px';
        div.style.zoom = '25%';
    }
}
})(49, 1);
</script><![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
     </div>
    </div>
<div class="container" id="container">
<table class="copyTable" id="copyTable">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
      <th>Column 11</th>
      <th>Column 12</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="3">
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="4">
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="item" data-id="5">
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="6">
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="item" data-id="7">
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="8">
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Thanks to this I have also been able to reduce the loading time it takes for the popup to close after the ✕ button has been clicked.